# Regular Expressions to Display Messages from a Text Log File

Tags: java, regex, logging

I'm trying to figure out how to use regular expressions to condense and sort the information I'm getting from this code. Here's the code and I'll explain as I go:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class baseline 
{

// Class level variables
   static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
   FileNotFoundException { // Start of main

   // Variables  
   String filename;

   // Connecting to the output file with a buffer
   PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(
                          new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter("chatOutput.log")));

   // Get the input file
   System.out.print("Please enter full name of the file: ");
   filename = sc.next();

   // Assign the name of the input file to a file object
   File log = new File(filename);
   String textLine = null; // Null
   String outLine = "";    // Null
   BufferedWriter bw = null;



  try
  {
  // assigns the input file to a filereader object
     BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log));

      sc = new Scanner(log);
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                String line=sc.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
                    System.out.println(line);
            } // End of while


  try
   {
     // Read data from the input file
    while((textLine = infile.readLine()) != null)
     {
    // Print to output file
    outLine = textLine;
    sc = new Scanner (outLine);
          while(sc.hasNext())
          {
               String line=sc.nextLine();
               if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
                    outFile.printf("%s\n",outLine);
          }// end of while 
      } // end of while
    } // end of try


   finally  // This gets executed even when an exception is thrown 
      {
    infile.close();
    outFile.close();
      } // End of finally
    } // End of try


  catch (FileNotFoundException nf) // Goes with first try
  {
   System.out.println("The file \""+log+"\" was not found"); 
  } // End of catch
  catch (IOException ioex) // Goes with second try
  {
   System.out.println("Error reading the file");
  } // End of catch

 } // end of main

} // end of class
```

So I'm reading an input file, getting only the lines that display "LANTALK", and printing them out to another file. And here is a sample of what the output looks like so far:

```
14:29:39.731 [D] [T:000FEC] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>922</MBXID><MBXTO>5608</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>It is mailing today right?
</MSGTEXT>
14:41:33.703 [D] [T:000FF4] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>929</MBXID><MBXTO>5601</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>Either today or tomorrow - 
still waiting to hear. </MSGTEXT>
```

And what I need is to get all of the characters between `<MSGTEXT>` and `</MSGTEXT>` to be able to display the message cleanly. How should I write this into the code to repeat with every "LANTALK" line and still write out correctly? Thanks!

Comment: What you have here is XML structure, and I seriously doubt that there would be a correct regexp to extract what you want - you will be better off parsing the thing as XML and looking at data then.

Comment: `grep LANTALK chatOutput.log`

Comment: Just as an example, consider this line: `<SUBTEXT>MetaTalk</SUBTEXT><MSGTEXT>So, what are we going to do about that problem with LanTalk channel?</MSGTEXT>`

Comment: Now that you have each line, take the part that comes after the third `]`, wrap in a top-level tag of some sort to make it legal XML, then easily parse the `MSGTEXT` out using an XML parser.

Comment: What would the code look like for that exactly to parse in XML? I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download).

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


....

while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("LANTALK")){
               Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
               Element  msg = doc.select("MSGTEXT").first();
               System.out.println(msg.text());
            }
                System.out.println(line);
        } // End of while
    .....
```

Comment: Okay so I'm trying this solution, but it's giving me an illegal start of expression error on the while and I don't understand why. All of my brackets are where they should be.

Comment: Check if you have put curely braces after your if conditions. In your code above there are no braces which is ok if you have a single statement, but if you want to group more than one statement in the if block then you have to use curely braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `MSGTEXT` using a regex:

```
<MSGTEXT>(.*?)</MSGTEXT>
```

However, some of the messages contain newlines, which makes this a bit more difficult.

One way to get past this is to read the entire file into a String, and then look for matches.

```
try {
    String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(log)));
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<MSGTEXT>(.*?)</MSGTEXT>", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Message: " + m.group(1));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Console output:

```
Message: It is mailing today right?

Message: Either today or tomorrow - 
still waiting to hear.
```

Keep in mind that if you are dealing with large log files this approach could use a lot of memory.

Also note that parsing XML with regex is generally considered a bad idea; it works fine for now, but if you plan on doing anything more complicated you should use an XML parser as others have suggested.

Comment: Do I need to import anything in addition to .io and .util?

Comment: @AlexanderVassios You will need `IOException` from `java.io`, `Files` and `Paths` from `java.nio.file`, and `Matcher` and `Pattern` from `java.util.regex`.

Comment: @InternetUnexlporer, no, not yet.

Comment: @AlexanderVassios Which part of the answer isn't working for you?

Comment: I've figured it out now and it's all working and displaying the message text. I'm just trying to figure out how to display the time before the text.

Comment: @AlexanderVassios You would need to add another capture group to the regex for that. If your problem has not been solved, then please update your question. If it has been solved, then please accept the best answer. Thank you.